# UserDefaults error - says that I am casting the wrong type

Tags: swift

The code below renders me an error that I have not encountered before with UserDefaults, any insight would be appreciated. Let me know if I have not provided enough context but I think that should be enough.

```
    import Foundation

final class AppStore {
    var myApps: [String]
    
    init() {
        UserDefaults.standard.register(defaults: [
            "myApps" : ["Telegram", "Snapchat", "Duolingo"]
        ])
        
        self.myApps = UserDefaults.standard.array(forKey: "myApps")
    }
}
```

[image: Text]

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/userdefaults/1417065-register

Comment: I having a working solution now using standard.object instead of standard.array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, value from `UserDefaults.standard.array(forKey: "myApps")` has `[Any]` type (An array of `Any` type objects). You should cast it to `[String]` before assigning to `self.myApps`.

For example:

```swift
self.myApps = UserDefaults.standard.array(forKey: "myApps") as? [String] ?? []
```